# What is the disadvantage of setting php.ini variables in the script?

Tags: php

What is the disadvantage of setting php.ini variables in the script ? (I set up in index.php - starting point of we site.)

My client saying I must add all ini variable changes in php.ini file not in the script .

Is there any security problem or runtime exceptions can happen if I set these variables in the script ?

Comment: ini_set function can be disabled with disable_functions. And you can't change values from your script

Comment: @hadvig . They thanx for the comment. I didn't know this before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some variables can not be set in the script, they only work in php.ini.

Putting the variables in php.ini is simpler - you don't have to do it for every single page. Remember index.php is just the front page to your site, I'm sure you'll have lots of other pages.

On the other hand putting them in the script can make it easier to distribute, since you don't need to do special configuration.

But, what variables do you need to set anyway? It's not that common to need to set a bunch of variables.

Comment: `index.php` is a file, not a *front page*. Many sites are built so that each and every HTTP request goes through `index.php`, i.e., there are *many pages*, but starting point for all of them is `index.php` (and not some mystic `gallery.php`, `guestbook.php` etc).

Comment: @binarylv I've seen such sites, and inevitably you find some pages that were written outside the framework.